Why do key signatures switch from flats to sharps at a certain mode brightness?
I'm looking at Hooktheory's Key Cheat Sheet Index. I've noticed that for each key signature where the root is a black note, the choice to use a sharp or flat in the key signature's name changes in relation to the mode's "brightness".
If I order the modes by brightness and place them in a table, see that each root note has a single point where the key signature name switches from the flat version to the sharp version as the modes get darker.



Mode
C# / Db
D# / Eb
F# / Gb
G# / Ab
A# / Bb




Lydian
Db
Eb
Gb
Ab
Bb


Major / Ionian
Db
Eb
F#
Ab
Bb


Mixolydian
C#
Eb
F#
Ab
Bb


Dorian
C#
Eb
F#
G#
Bb


Minor / Aeolian
C#
D#
F#
G#
Bb


Phyrigian
C#
D#
F#
G#
A#


Locrian
C#
D#
F#
G#
A#



Note that for Lydian, the brightest scale, the names are all flats. For Locrian, the darkest, the names are all sharps.
I understand the choice to use flats vs sharps is about not duplicating letters.
My question is, why does the name switch from flats to sharps at a certain brightness? What is the relationship between a mode's brightness and whether the key signature should be represented in flats or sharps?

What does "brightness" mean here? Some kind of perceived tonal color, or simply "how many black keys are involved"?

Brighter modes have more sharps. For example, Lydian is the major scale with a sharp 4th. Mixolydian is darker than major because it has the flat 7th.

I think the term "brightness" might eventually confuse you.  Describing modes as being bright (closer to lydian) or dark (closer to locrian) is common.  But we don't describe keys as being bright or dark based on it having more sharps or flats.
There is a well known effect that modulating to a key with 1 or 2 more sharps sounds a bit "brighter", and the opposite direction sounds a bit "darker", but at a certain point the keys are too distantly related for this effect to really be apparent (e.g. adding 7 sharps) and beyond that it becomes sonically equivalent to adding flats.

Let's start by rearranging your table to put the black notes that are spelled most frequently as flats on the left, and those that are spelled most frequently as sharps on the right.  I've also made a small modification in the six-sharp/six-flat cases.



Mode
Bb/A#
Eb/D#
Ab/G#
Db/C#
Gb/F#




Lydian
Bb
Eb
Ab
Db
Gb


Major / Ionian
Bb
Eb
Ab
Db
F#/Gb


Mixolydian
Bb
Eb
Ab
C#/Db
F#


Dorian
Bb
Eb
G#/Ab
C#
F#


Minor / Aeolian
Bb
D#/Eb
G#
C#
F#


Phrygian
A#/Bb
D#
G#
C#
F#


Locrian
A#
D#
G#
C#
F#



Now let's do some math.  Start in the upper-left corner, Bb Lydian.  That's a mode of F major and so has one flat.  Every time you move to the right you gain a flat (going down the circle of fifths), and every time you move down you gain a flat.  When you have five or less flats, you use flats. When you have six flats it's ambiguous, since you'd have six sharps as well (hence the diagonal going from A#/Bb Phrygian to F#/Gb Ionian).  Once you go further down and to the right you have seven or more flats, and five or less sharps, so you use sharps.
Incidentally, you could continue this table one more column to the right or left.  One more column on the left would be F/E#.  And you'd get that all the modes in F are spelled that way - except that F Locrian could be E# Locrian.  This sounds insane, but F Locrian has six flats and E# Locrian has six sharps, so it's correct.  Similarly, you could add a column on the right for Cb/B, and you'd have the same thing, with B Lydian having six sharps and Cb Lydian having six flats.  (I think a reasonable person would refer to these as F Locrian and B Lydian, respectively - seems like the tiebreaker should go to not using the accidental in the name of the mode.)

Interestingly, Hook Theory have indeed gone for E# Locrian. I assume this is because F Locrian would have a B and a Bb, and they chose to avoid duplicate letters

F locrian would have Bb and Cb.  We don't duplicate letters.

Yeah, I intended to spell it out but was trying to keep the answer relatively short - F Locrian is F, Gb, Ab, Bb, Cb, Db, Eb (everything flat except for the named note) while E# Locrian is E#, F#, G#, A#, B, C#, D#.

It's just the choice of simpler key signature. For example, C# major has seven sharps; Db major has five flats. So the latter's signature is simpler.
Bb major has two flats; A# major has ten sharps (that's four notes with a sharp and three with a double sharp), you probably don't want to use that.
C# Dorian, being a mode of B major, has five sharps; Db Dorian, a mode of Cb major (why yes, that absolutely exists too), has seven flats, and like you aren't likely to choose Cb major over B major, you aren't likely to choose Db Dorian either.

That makes sense, but my question is, why would the signature change at a certain point on the above table, as the modes get brighter/darker?

@MisplayedPiece "Bright" and "dark" are terms from the school of "thought" that postulates "major keys happy, minor keys sad". Let's look at what's really going on, in inpartial, practical terms. What you have there is the modes arranged by the intervals above the first degree their scales form. In Lydian mode, all steps where applicable are a major interval above the tonic and on top of that there's an augmented fourth. In Ionian, the fourth is perfect, all relevant steps are major. Mixolydian gives you a minor seventh. Dorian has a minor seventh and a minor third.

With each line, there's one more minor interval above the tonic, until you run out of them, and finally the Locrian mode has not only all possible minor intervals above tonic but also a diminished fifth. In each line, there's exactly one tone in the scale whose interval above the tonic is a semitone smaller than in the previous. In other words, if you've got the modes arranged like this, each next mode from the same root has either one less sharp or one more flat in the signature.

So going down the table, one of the two enharmonic scales you're considering is losing sharps and the other is gathering flats. In Lydian mode, all these options with sharps have too many sharps, while those with flats have nicely few flats, so flats are preferable. Then from some point on, the one with flats has too many flats, and the one with sharps has nicely few sharps.

Right, so getting "brighter" means adding a sharp to the sharp signature and loosing a flat from the flat signature, then at some point there becomes more sharps than flats, and at that point it makes sense to start choosing the flat signature because it has fewer flats than the sharp signature has sharps. That explains it! Thanks

It's not related — at least not directly — to brightness; it has to do with the number of sharps/flats in the key signature. This can also be looked at in terms of the relative major key signature. It is convention to choose key signatures with the least number of sharps or flats, with F#/Gb being neutral in that regard.
For example:
C#/Db



Mode
Scale
b/#
Rel. Maj.




Lydian
Db Eb F  G  Ab Bb C
4b
Ab



C# D# E# Fx G# A# B#
8#









Ionian
Db Eb F  Gb Ab Bb C
5b
Db



C# D# E# F# G# A# B#
7#









Mixolydian
Db Eb F  Gb Ab Bb Cb
6b
Gb/F#



C# D# E# F# G# A# B
6#









Dorian
Db Eb Fb Gb Ab Bb Cb
7b
B



C# D# E  F# G# A# B
5#









Aeolian
Db Eb Fb Gb Ab Bbb Cb
8b
E



C# D# E  F# G# A   B
4#









Phrygian
Db Ebb Fb Gb Ab Bbb Cb
9b
A



C# D   E  F# G# A   B
3#









Locrian
Db Ebb Fb Gb Abb Bbb Cb
10b
D



C# D   E  F# G   A   B
2#





Actually this table shows the relationship I was looking for. As the modes get darker going down the table, the number of flats increase and the number of sharps decrease. At a point, the number of sharps decreases below the number of flats, where the signature with the least number of sharps/flats would switch

@MisplayedPiece The table also shows something else. If one considers the Relative Major column, it shows that moving around the circle of fifths counter-clockwise, the major keys grow darker, and they grow brighter if moving clockwise. This is equivalent to saying that adding sharps makes a key brighter and adding flats makes keys darker. This will hold true for any individual mode. Given any mode, F (mode) will be darker than C (mode), and G (mode) will be brighter than C (mode), for example.

A nitpick mostly just because it is left out: having less sharp/flats is not the only reason to pick a specific key. Depending on if the piece moves through many keys or is written for certain instruments picking a key with more sharps/flats may be ideal within reason of course. Example: you star a piece in C# minor and eventually go to C# major you would not put it in Db because it has less accidentals.

@Dom All true, just note I was referring to picking key signatures, in which the convention is to use the one with fewer accidentals. So, for example, it's not uncommon for a piece in C# minor to modulate to Db major. Chopin's Waltz in C# minor, op. 64 no. 2 (ISMLP), makes this particular modulation.

Check out the gifs I attached to a prior answer: https://music.stackexchange.com/a/127379/9426

If I understand your question correctly, this has nothing to do with the brightness or darkness of a mode, it simply has to do with the key signature of the parent key. Brightness or darkness has nothing to do with accidentals, it has to do with the quality of the scale (major or minor) and the relationship of the scale degrees to the root of the scale.
Here are a few examples from your chart:
Db Lydian: parent key is Ab, 4 flats. It’s not going to be G# or 8 sharps.
F# Dorian: parent key is E major, 4 sharps, not Gb minor, 8 flats.
Some keys and modes can be on the fence, for example the modes built on F#/Gb are both 6 sharps and flats respectively.so all of those modes can be either sharp or flat. Also, the keys C# and Cb are sometimes used which are 7 sharps and flats respectively so they can also go either way.


I've noticed that for each key signature where the root is a black note, the choice to use a sharp or flat in the key signature's name changes in relation to the mode's "brightness".

In a comment, you wrote

Brighter modes have more sharps. For example, Lydian is the major scale with a sharp 4th. Mixolydian is darker than major because it has the flat 7th

Consider the scale of the A♯ Ionian mode: A♯, B♯, C♯♯, D♯, E♯, F♯♯,  G♯♯, A♯.
This scale is useful as a device for demoralizing music students, nothing more.  It requires a key signature with 10 sharps, theoretically, or four sharps and three double sharps in practice.  By contrast, the B♭ version is, well, normal, requiring just two flats.
The first rule is: never use a key signature with double sharps or double flats (i.e., theoretically more than seven sharps or flats).
The second rule is: prefer the key signature with fewer signs; you can take accidentals into account (e.g., there's a stronger preference for E♭ minor over D♯ minor than for G♭ major over F♯ major because of the frequent chromatic raising of the sixth and seventh degrees in minor).  Sometimes you'll see  a signature of seven sharps or flats, but composers will usually use the enharmonically equivalent signature with five flats or sharps, respectively.  See for example Beethoven's Moonlight Sonata, where the outer movements are in C♯ minor (four sharps) and the middle movement in D♭ major (five flats) instead of C♯ major (seven sharps).
Consequently, as you add sharps ("brighten," under your definition), you reach a point where your key signature exceeds the limits of these rules.  A more careful version of the table in your answer would list two options at this transition point (both F♯ and G♭ for Ionian, for example) and possibly even note the seven-symbol possibilities parenthetically, since they do actually appear (in tonal compositions, at least) but are probably best avoided without a very good reason.
In conclusion, to answer your question

why does the name switch from flats to sharps at a certain brightness? What is the relationship between a mode's brightness and whether the key signature should be represented in flats or sharps?

The "brighter" a mode is, the more sharps it has in its key signature, and the more likely it is to exceed the six-sharp recommended limit (or the seven-sharp hard limit) where you should switch to the flat-side enharmonic equivalent.

My understanding from very old anecdotal theory lessons is that it is largely that sharp keys tend to be used for minor, or minor-ish keys (e.g., C# minor, G# minor) while flat keys tend to be used for major and major-ish keys (e.g. Ab Major, Db Major).
While is certainly not an exhausive or comprehensive list by any means, Wikipedia's list of symphonies by key notably is missing the following key pairs:
A# Major | Bb Major | A# minor | Bb minor
^^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^^^
C# Major | Db Major | C# minor | Db minor
^^^^^^^^                         ^^^^^^^^
D# Major | Eb Major | D# minor | Eb minor
^^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^^^
F# Major | Gb Major | F# minor | Gb minor
           ^^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^^^
G# Major | Ab Major | G# minor | Ab minor
^^^^^^^^                         ^^^^^^^^

There are still more major flats and minor sharps than not, though given anomalies F# Major (1), Bb minor (15), and Eb minor (2), I'm hesitant to buy too deeply into this theory. Perhaps there is further evidence out there.
One other very peculiar thing on this list is that the Bb minor symphonies are almost all 1900s or newer, and mostly by Russian composers.
